# scanner + loop single line

Tags: java, loops, java.util.scanner

Ask the user to enter in a number, then you can print out the number of many `*` on the screen without spaces or newlines. You may use your `Scanner` object in numbers 5, 6 and 9 also.

Input:

```
7
```

Output:

```
*******
```

I can do this but I can't do it in a single line all the astericks

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class  {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        int x;
        int i;

        System.out.println("Enter a number:");
        x = scan.nextInt();

        for (i = 0; i < x; i++) {
            System.out.println("*");
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: If this was an assignment that you just copied and pasted, the school should be paying you to go to it because that grammar is TERRIBLE!!!

Comment: What do you mean by "You may use your Scanner object in numbers 5, 6 and 9 also!!" and is your question "how to do this in a single line?"?

Comment: "I can do this but I can't do it in a single line all the astericks" - why do you think you want to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a for-loop like so changing `println` to just `print` so you print the `*` on the same line:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Please enter a number:");
    int inputNumber = sc.nextInt();
    
    for(int i=0;i<inputNumber;i++) {
      System.out.print('*');
    }
  }
}
```

Try it [here!](https://repl.it/FF6I/1)

**Note**: You can initialize `i` within the for-loop and don't need to declare it beforehand

Answer (score 0):

You should to use

```
System.out.print("*");
```

and not

```
System.out.println("*");
```

Because `println` return to line and `print` not.

Hope this can help you.

## Note

Your class need a name in your question you do :

```
class  {
```

and this wrong in java, so you need to declare your class like this:

```
class  nameClass {
  //Your code
}
```

## Take a look here :

[Getting Started](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/getStarted/index.html)

and here:

[Arrays](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html)

Answer (score 0):

It's my first response i hope to help you...

Try

```
System.out.print("*");
```

if you use

```
System.out.println("*");
```

Your program will do a line jump...

Answer (score 0):

To print all the asterisks in a single line, use `print` instead of `println`:

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
int x;
int i;

System.out.println("Enter a number:");
x = scan.nextInt();

for (i = 0; i < x; i++) {
    System.out.print("*"); // <- note the difference here!
}
```

Why? Let's look at the [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#print(java.lang.String)):

`print(String)`:

> Prints a string. If the argument is null then the string "null" is printed. Otherwise, the string's characters are converted into bytes according to the platform's default character encoding, and these bytes are written in exactly the manner of the write(int) method.

`println(String)`:

> Prints a String and then terminate the line. This method behaves as though it invokes `print(String)` and then `println()`.

So `println(String)` calls `print(String)` then `println()`. What does `println()` do?

> Terminates the current line by writing the line separator string. The line separator string is defined by the system property line.separator, and is not necessarily a single newline character ('\n').

Now you see the difference! `println(String)` prints a new line after it prints the string while `print(String)` does not!

Here's a cleaned up version of your code:

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Enter a number:");
int x = scan.nextInt();

for (int i = 0; i < x; i++) {
    System.out.print("*");
}
```